Can login as superuser but not as normal user
i have made a super user and registering other users. but only able to log in as superuser and when i try to login as normal user its shows "Invalid phone number or password".
Can someone help me with this
models.py
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, phone_number, email=None, name=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
        if not phone_number:
            raise ValueError('The phone number must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email) if email else None
        user = self.model(phone_number=phone_number, name=name, email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, phone_number, email=None, name=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        return self.create_user(phone_number, email, name, password, **extra_fields)

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    phone_number = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=20)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='')
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_superuser=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'phone_number'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.phone_number


views.py
@api_view(['POST'])
def login_api(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = LoginSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            phone_number = serializer.validated_data.get('phone_number')
            password = serializer.validated_data.get('password')

            user = authenticate(request, phone_number=phone_number, password=password)
            
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return Response({'message': 'Login successful'})
                else:
                    return Response({'error': 'User account is disabled'}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
            else:
                return Response({'error': 'Invalid phone number or password'}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
        
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    
    return Response({'error': 'Method not allowed'}, status=status.HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)


settings.py
AUTH_USER_MODEL='detectapp.CustomUser'
I made a customusermodel to log in with phone number. But not able to resolve the issue.

can you please provide the error details?

When I try to login it shows "Invalid phone number or password"

At first, this example is not working at all:
name = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='') # not null=False

in create_user, create_superuser you give name=None, and user can not be saved. You got an error: NOT NULL constraint failed: detectapp_customuser.name
At second, if you solve all problem with csrf, you should get
{
    "message": "Login successful" 
}

Your example works for me, although you didn't provide the serializer and drf settings.
After some investigation, hopefully I have found your problem:
If you create a user via CustomUserAdmin(admins.ModelAdmin), the database will store the raw password, not the hash.
This is because the ModelAdmin saves the model directly to the database, not through create_user.
The same is, if you try to create user directly, not through create_user.
To avoid this behavior, you can use the following:
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk and not self._password:
            self.set_password(self.password)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

In my example, self._password for new objects is always None if you haven't called set_password before.

Bro what exactly you changed? I am able to create users but not able to login.Phone number is used for login

how you create users for login?

i think i solve your problem. I've update the answer.
